# PK and FK naming Convention in code first

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I like my pk and fk columns to not have "_dbo." as part of the name. Is there a configuration available in Entity framework code first?

For instance, I have a table called PunchCard. The Pk get named to PK_dbo.PunchCard. I am looking to have it be PK_PunchCard

For FK, It will say FK_dbo.PunchCard_dbo.Employee_EmployeetId. I am looking for it say FK_PunchCard_Employee.

Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Which Sql server edition are you using. I have created the table with the same name dbo.PunchCard with one column id . Another way  is to define a constraint for primary key where you can give name as you want.`See the attached output[image: PK Naming convention]

Comment: Those are auto created by entity framework (Code first)